# Play muted loop video on Streamlit

Tags: python, html, video, streamlit

I am trying to display a muted loop video on my Streamlit homepage, running on Chrome:

```
col1, col2 = st.columns([1, 1])

video_html = """
            <video width="320" height="240" autoplay loop>
            <source 
            src="resources/video (online-video-cutter.com).mp4" 
            type="video/mp4" />
            </video>

        """
col2.markdown(video_html, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

However, as soon as I run the app, I cannot see anything (literally, a blank page).

How can I correctly autoplay the muted video and solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these attributes:

```
autoplay="true" -- For autoplay
muted="true" -- For mute
loop="true" -- For Loop
```

```html
<video controls width="250" autoplay="true" muted="true" loop="true">
<source 
            src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm" 
            type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

mdn:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-muted
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-autoplay

Comment: Thank you for your feedback; it now works. What about the loop component?

Comment: Updated the ``` loop="true" ``` please review